# Using a function to make code simpler

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a function that will enable me to change the console color quicker.
It would be something like:

```
public static void setColor(string color)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.color;
    }
```

and then instead of typing out the middle part I would be able to quickly set the color by just typing setColor(blue).
Is this possible in any way?

Comment: it is possible to call the method to set the console color. but what is not working for you it is not clear in your question..

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what "quicker" means to you here. But if you feel the need to do this, you're probably using your tools wrong.

Even ignoring the fact the you can't pass the string "blue" and have it work there (since it's a string, not a piece of code), there's really nothnig quicker in writing `setColor("blue")` than writing `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue`, even if your typing speed is very slow.

Instead of creating additional layers of abstractions that do nothing but save very, very few keystrokes, learn to use the tools you have better. Learn to use the IDE's autocomplete and intellisense, so that your can start typing "Console", see when intellisense matches it, then simply press `.` and start typing "Foreground" and see how many keys you need for it to be caught (hint: very few).

The disadvantages of creating a wrapper method is that it masks what is actually happening (wait, is it setting foreground color or background color?) and a month from now, you might not remember. It means *other* developers won't know what's going on - this might be a personal project, but it's a bad habit to have going forward. And it means that this method now needs to be available everywhere, in every class you write, which is also messy.

This method adds almost nothing. I would avoid using it, and look for other ways to "increase productivity" - because saving a few keystrokes *isn't* the way. Most of your time as a developer is spent thinking and looking things up, not *typing*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx) and just look for the color in the [ConsoleColor Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies constants that define foreground and background colors for
>   the console.

**Exmaple**

```
public static void setColor(string color)
{
    try
    {
         Console.ForegroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), color, true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //catch error for an invalid color
    }
}
```